# pivotal cloud foundry throwing error with node

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, deployment, cloud-foundry

- I am trying to include node agent in my pcf.
- but I am getting below error after I execute this command cf restage webcomponent
  Failed to compile droplet: Failed to run all supply scripts: exit status 14
  Exit status 223
  Staging failed: STG: Exited with status 223
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- am I doing anything wrong with my environment variables of pcf

**refrence link** https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO42/Install+the+Node.js+Agent
https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/1-12/buildpacks/node/node-tips.html#env-var

**User Provided Environment Variables**

```
GRANT_TYPE                   implicit
OPTIMIZE_MEMORY              true
SSO_IDENTITY_PROVIDERS       uaa
http_proxy                   http://proxy.blanket.com:80
https_proxy                  http://proxy.blanket.com:80
Name                         Value
```

**environment variables**

```
{
  "staging_env_json": {},
  "running_env_json": {},
  "system_env_json": {
    "VCAP_SERVICES": {
      "p-identity": [
        {
          "credentials": {
            "client_id": "788787878723232323873287",
            "client_secret": "ewqyueyuewuwi87323287ejhwweiu",
            "auth_domain": "https://app-luagh.com"
          },
          "syslog_drain_url": null,
          "volume_mounts": [],
          "label": "p-identity",
          "provider": null,
          "plan": "app-auth",
          "name": "sso",
          "tags": []
        }
      ],
      "user-provided": [
        {
          "credentials": {
            "uri": "http://we.laugh.com"
          },
          "syslog_drain_url": "",
          "volume_mounts": [],
          "label": "user-provided",
          "name": "crystalreports",
          "tags": []
        }
      ],
      "appdynamics": [
        {
          "credentials": {
            "account-name": "technology-blanket",
            "port": "78787878",
            "account-access-key": "fdae8266e8b3",
            "host-name": "technology-blanket.saas.appdynamics.com",
            "ssl-enabled": "true"
          },
          "syslog_drain_url": null,
          "volume_mounts": [],
          "label": "appdynamics",
          "provider": null,
          "plan": "AppDynamics",
          "name": "appdynamics",
          "tags": [
            "appdynamics",
            "apm",
            "mobile real-user monitoring",
            "browser real-user monitoring",
            "database monitoring",
            "server monitoring",
            "application analytics"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "application_env_json": {
    "VCAP_APPLICATION": {
      "cf_api": "https://api.wdhjhj.laugh.com",
      "limits": {
        "fds": 16384,
        "mem": 8192,
        "disk": 2048
      },
      "application_name": "webcomponent",
      "application_uris": [
        "here.laugh.com"
      ],
      "name": "webcomponent",
      "space_name": "app-DEV",
      "space_id": "aeryuryw2872jk32iuk",
      "uris": [
        "here.laugh.com"
      ],
      "users": null,
      "application_id": "jkdsjkdsjk89989889",
      "version": "yuwrhjyuwuyw-237823878723kj",
      "application_version": "yhjjhhjhj-yuyuuy877887"
    }
  }
}
```

**$ cf restage webcomponent**

```
Restaging app webcomponent in org example-app / space sublime-text as 788781287...

Staging app and tracing logs...
   Downloading build artifacts cache...
   Downloaded app package (6M)
   Downloaded build artifacts cache (26.2M)
   Staging...
   -----> Download go 1.9
   -----> Running go build supply
   -----> Nodejs Buildpack version 1.6.8
   -----> Installing binaries
          engines.node (package.json): unspecified
          engines.npm (package.json): unspecified (use default)
   -----> Installing node 4.8.4
          Download [https://buildpacks.cloudfoundry.org/dependencies/node/node-4.8.4-linux-x64-230101ff.tgz]
          **WARNING** Node version not specified in package.json. See: http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/node/node-tips.html
          Using default npm version: 2.15.11
   -----> Installing yarn 1.1.0
          Download [https://buildpacks.cloudfoundry.org/dependencies/yarn/yarn-v1.1.0-26588f71.tar.gz]
          Installed yarn 1.1.0
   -----> Creating runtime environment
          NODE_HOME=/tmp/contents811454074/deps/0/node
          PRO TIP: It is recommended to vendor the application's Node.js dependencies
          Visit http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/node/index.html#vendoring
          NODE_ENV=production
          NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
          NODE_VERBOSE=false
          NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
          NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
          - .npm
   -----> Restoring cache
          Loading 3 from cacheDirectories (default):
          - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
          - .cache/yarn (not cached - skipping)
          Installing node modules (package.json)
   -----> Building dependencies
   > uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall /tmp/app/node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
   > node lib/post_install.js
   > SPORTS@1.0.0 postinstall /tmp/app
   > webpack -p --config ./webpack.prod.js --progress --profile --bail
    10% building modules 0/1 modules 1 active ...der/src/index.js!/tmp/app/app/main.ts
   [at-loader] Using typescript@2.5.3 from typescript and "tsconfig.json" from /tmp/app/tsconfig.json.
 30% building modules 174/183 modules 9 active .../app/app/services/animalsService.ts
 49% building modules 333/374 modules 41 active ...ar/http/src/backends/browser_jsonp.js
 67% building modules 519/537 modules 18 active ...ar/router/src/routlib/zlib/adler32.js
 69% building modules 698/707 modules 9 active ...mponents/title/titles-allocation.html
54382ms building modules
   37ms sealing
   0ms basic module optimization
   1ms optimizing
   1ms chunk optimization
   42ms module optimization
   0ms advanced chunk optimization
   0ms basic chunk optimization
   0ms advanced module optimization
   0ms chunk modules optimization
   0ms module and chunk tree optimization
   0ms advanced chunk modules optimization
   12ms module reviving
   8ms module order optimization
   5ms module id optimization
   0ms chunk order optimization
   0ms chunk reviving
   20ms chunk id optimization
   88ms hashing
   1ms module assets processing
   164ms chunk assets processing
   238ms additional chunk assets processing
   0ms recording
   95741ms additional asset processing
    94% asset optimization
   [at-loader] Checking started in a separate process...
   1ms chunk asset optimization
   [at-loader] Checking finished with 4 errors
7885ms asset optimization
   198ms emitting
       app.js  6.48 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  app
   index.html  2.38 kB          [emitted]
      [6] ./app/mobile/mobile.service.ts 2.38 kB {0} [built]
      [7] ./app/services/nailService.ts 3.19 kB {0} [built]
          [] -> factory:9141ms building:209ms dependencies:674ms = 10024ms
          [] -> factory:92ms building:1167ms dependencies:9284ms = 10543ms
          [] -> factory:3595ms building:118ms dependencies:755ms = 4468ms
    [497] ./app/main.ts 7.37 kB {0} [built]
          [] -> factory:35ms building:756ms dependencies:42213ms = 43004ms
    [625] ./app/app.component.ts 53.9 kB {0} [built]
          [] -> factory:47ms building:1654ms dependencies:26464ms = 28165ms
       + 817 hidden modules
   ERROR in [at-loader] ./app/components/swimming-birds/playing-birds-laughing.ts:8316:50
       TS2341: Property 'gaming' is private and only accessible within class 'playingrcap'.
          [0] ./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./app/index.html 2.52 kB {0} [built]
   Hash: 6ad9b11d2fa7af59bf00
   Version: webpack 3.7.1
   Time: 158876ms
          [] -> factory:10654ms building:378ms dependencies:85ms = 11117ms
          [] -> factory:16964ms building:327ms dependencies:8106ms = 25397ms
          [] -> factory:14883ms building:371ms dependencies:57ms = 15311ms
        Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
      [1] ./app/services/SPORTS.service.ts 19.4 kB {0} [built]
     [35] ./app/services/decodeService.ts 3.25 kB {0} [built]
          [] -> factory:7496ms building:440ms dependencies:1ms = 7937ms
          [] -> factory:19193ms building:1177ms dependencies:0ms = 20370ms
          [] -> factory:8435ms building:188ms dependencies:0ms = 8623ms
          [] -> factory:9147ms building:832ms dependencies:7129ms = 17108ms
     [59] ./app/services/egplayingService.ts 3.57 kB {0} [built]
    [304] ./app/mobile/mobilions.ts 563 bytes {0} [built]
    [375] ./app/services/clipboard.service.ts 3.78 kB {0} [built]
     [18] ./app/services/playingService.ts 15 kB {0} [built]
     [70] ./app/services/animalsService.ts 968 bytes {0} [built]
    [133] ./app/services/canDeactivate.service.ts 2.91 kB {0} [built]
           factory:27ms building:6978ms = 7005ms
    [594] ./app/app.module.ts 35 kB {0} [built]
    [789] ./app/app.routing.ts 42.1 kB {0} [built]
          [] -> factory:29907ms building:4964ms dependencies:0ms = 34871ms
    [827] ./app/services/CanActivateViaAuthGuard.ts 1.42 kB {0} [built]
          [] -> factory:29945ms building:5159ms dependencies:2681ms = 37785ms
   45:15-36 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
   WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/system_js_ng_module_factory_loader.js
   WARNING in ./node_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/system_js_ng_module_factory_loader.js
   57:15-102 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
   ERROR in [at-loader] ./app/components/swimming-birds/playing-birds-laughing.ts:8330:43
   ERROR in [at-loader] ./app/components/swimming-birds/playing-birds-laughing.ts:8319:61
   ERROR in [at-loader] ./app/components/swimming-birds/playing-birds-laughing.ts:8370:43
       TS2341: Property 'gaming' is private and only accessible within class 'playingrcap'.
       TS2341: Property 'gaming' is private and only accessible within class 'playingrcap'.
       TS2341: Property 'gaming' is private and only accessible within class 'playingrcap'.
               factory:7018ms building:13ms = 7031ms
        1 asset
   Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
   npm ERR! not with npm itself.
   npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
   npm ERR!
   npm ERR!     npm owner ls SPORTS
   npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-96-generic
   npm ERR! npm  v2.15.11
   npm ERR! node v4.8.4
   npm ERR!
   npm ERR! argv "/tmp/contents811454074/deps/0/node/bin/node" "/tmp/contents811454074/deps/0/bin/npm" "install" "--unsafe-perm" "--userconfig" "/tmp/app/.npmrc" "--cache" "/tmp/app/.npm"
   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
   npm ERR! Exit status 2
   npm ERR!     npm bugs SPORTS
   npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
   npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the SPORTS package,
   npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
   npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
   npm ERR! SPORTS@1.0.0 postinstall: `webpack -p --config ./webpack.prod.js --progress --profile --bail`
   npm ERR! Failed at the SPORTS@1.0.0 postinstall script 'webpack -p --config ./webpack.prod.js --progress --profile --bail'.
   npm ERR!     webpack -p --config ./webpack.prod.js --progress --profile --bail
   npm ERR!     /tmp/app/npm-debug.log
   npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
          **ERROR** Unable to build dependencies: exit status 1
   Failed to compile droplet: Failed to run all supply scripts: exit status 14
   Exit status 223
   Staging failed: STG: Exited with status 223
   Stopping instance affd069e-bf48-4ab4-b613-54913c3abf23
   Destroying container
   Successfully destroyed container
Error staging application: App staging failed in the buildpack compile phase
FAILED
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be typescript errors from the angular code, try addressing

```
TS2341: Property 'gaming' is private and only accessible within class 'playingrcap'.
```

if you're using `allData` in the template then you need to change it from `private` to `public`. Guessing from this file `./app/components/swimming-birds/playing-birds-laughing.ts`

Comment: for PCF will this be problem...since in local application was running successfully

Comment: This shouldn't have anything to do with PCF itself. This is an angular issue

Comment: if we fix that issue...will this issue will be fixed 
```
scripts: exit status 14 Exit status 223 Staging failed: STG: Exited with status 223
```

Comment: hey if I try to execute this command in my application...I see thiss issue...do I need to install something

```
 $ ng build --prod
bash: ng: command not found
```

Comment: You will need npm install then run `npm install -g @angular/cli` as well as `npm install` in the angular directory

Comment: I am using angular 2 only...is there any other package where I can test since angular cli works only with 4

Comment: hey other than installing angular cli is it possible to run manually...since its not allowing me to install angular cli

Comment: short answer, yes you will need angular cli for this

Comment: Without using angular-cli can't I do prod build